# time conversion to numeric format

Tags: r, date, time, numeric

I have data in time format, e.g. "15:57:41". After converting it into numeric format using `as.numeric()` in R, the converted value is 0.6650579. Can anybody please explain the logic in the manual calculation behind this? How is the time getting converted to this numeric value?

Comment: This is pretty clearly NOT using POSIX date-time format. It would be clearer if you posted first a library call, probably for pkg-chron, and then built an R object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fraction of a day:

```
library(chron)
as.numeric(times("15:57:41"))
## [1] 0.6650579
```

Manually convert hours/minutes/seconds to fraction of day:

```
## (hours + (minutes + seconds/60)/60)/24
(15+(57+41/60)/60)/24
## [1] 0.6650579
```

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.